# Fitch deduction question, ((A ∧ B) → C ⊢ A → (B → C))

Tags: proof-writing, natural-deduction

I have been at this for 6 hours. I can't figure it out and I don't know what else to do. Please help. My problem is I don't know how to do this without assuming A&B. Here's the furthest I got:

(A ∧ B) → C ⊢ A → (B → C)

[My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHEVK.jpg)

Comment: Please write the work you did in the body of the question. Outside links are not preferred unless absolutely unavoidable.

Comment: I don't quite understand why we would begin by assuming $A \wedge B$ in the first place, if we remove that then we would get $A \wedge B$ from the assumptions of $A$ and $B$ and $\wedge$-introduction, and then the rest would remain mostly the same

Comment: Thank you. I got it! I don't know why I couldn't get it. Thanks so much you are a hero